# localhost on MacOSX connection refused

Tags: macos, nginx, localhost, firewall

I've had my app running on localhost port 80 via nginx on my mac for quite awhile. Recently I did some software updates and was trying to run other apps on different ports and now I can't run my first app on localhost:80.

I've very confused on where to start but think this is a firewall issue based on the following:

```
Tims-MacBook-Pro-2:html TimPeterson$ telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

pointing the browser to `http://localhost` gives this `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost`

thoughts?

Comment: The answer is provided in this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607457/cant-run-web-app-on-localhost-mac

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the answer you're referring to on that link. I also got this error (along with MySql error) after installing ngnix, but I think via a different method than you.

Comment: I'm guessing @timpeterson is referring to that you should be using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 4):

you may want to run

```
apachectl configtest
```

first.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It will run a test in your terminal and show you syntax errors and such so you know exactly what to fix for your apache to run again

Comment: `Syntax OK` it says, still `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED `

Answer (score 0):

My problem was specific, but might help another user. On Mac OS go to system preferences/sharing and check your computer name/localhost name (click edit to see the localhost name). My computer was reset by Apple in a non-English speaking country. They stuck some of their language in my computer name (great idea!) and it broke the Cisco login to localhost

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was uncommenting the following line in my /etc/hosts file:

```
::1    localhost
```