# Connection refused on PHP application on nginx on my Mac

Tags: php, macos, nginx, mnpp

I have an [nginx app](https://github.com/jyr/MNPP) that was running on localhost and now I can no longer access it. I'm truly at a loss for how to diagnose the problem.

Some things I've investigated:

- `TimPeterson$ sudo lsof -i :80` ->shows tons of stuff, but nothing that looks like my app
- System Preferences -> sharing ->toggle "web sharing" -> doesn't help

I'm not a total noob in that I've had this server running for over a year but obviously I did something or some software update jacked some part of the configuration.

Comment: perhaps you can check your document root location if it has changed, also, please tell us what do you get as result to get a better idea

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae the document root has not changed, i'm more inclined to think its some permission issue as `telnet localhost 80` says "connection refused"

Comment: do you get any error ? what's not working exactly ?

Comment: `netstat -na | grep 80` and see if anything is listening on port TCP 80.

Comment: @SB. thanks, hmm it doesn't look like it right? http://imgur.com/tgXQXiw

Comment: Are you sure nginx is running?  `ps aux | grep nginx` - if not, look @ nginx logs to see if anything is messed up

Comment: @SB. it looks like Nginx is running, right?  `Tims-MacBook-Pro-2:html TimPeterson$ ps aux | grep nginx
TimPeterson    29607   2.5  0.0  2434892    548 s001  S+    9:58AM   0:00.01 grep nginx`

Comment: @SB. could this be a permission issue as `telnet localhost 80` says "connection refused"?

Comment: Nope - that's the grep command you just ran ;) - not a permissions issue - nothing is listening on 80

Comment: @SB. so if Nginx isn't running, despite me running my app this could be an [MNPP](https://github.com/jyr/MNPP) issue I guess? I've stopped and started this MAMP/WAMP-like server for over a year now so no idea what would have locked it in the off position despite me starting it.

Comment: Did you try `sudo mnpp nginx start` ? - comment discussion is getting too long..

Comment: What has always worked for me in the past is this: `TimPeterson$ sudo mnpp --php53 --start`. Sorry for so much comments, might you be able to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40052/discussion-between-sb-and-tim-peterson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check the error log for anything related to nginx.  MNPP appears to install nginx in `/Applications/MNPP/Library/nginx`.

Comment: which error log, please? Is there one specific to nginx?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if its the same in your case, but some time, localhost wont work on my mac os x

Try to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` and if it worked, check your `/private/etc/hosts` file

Comment: -@Abu I didn't change the /etc/hosts file. Also, my /etc/hosts already is `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: did you give it a try with `127.0.0.1`?  if I remember well I problem long ago where I could only run my apps on `127.0.0.1` without having my hosts changed

Comment: yes `http://127.0.0.1/` doesn't work nor does `http://localhost`.  Whereas before both of those worked.